# hotel booking SQL query not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a two tables:

**Room**

```
id  
category_id  
name  
description 
image  
price  
arrival_date  
depature_date  
status
```

**Booking**

```
id  
name  
email  
mobile  
category_id  
room_id  
arrival  
departure
```

Q1. How can I check if a room is available or not for customers?
Q2. I want to show the room list that is empty for user input date

I am using this query and it gives me `error #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

```
SELECT * FROM room WHERE status = '1' AND id NOT IN 
    (SELECT * FROM booking
    WHERE arrival='$arrival' 
    OR ( arrival BETWEEN '$arrival' AND '$departure' ) )

SELECT * FROM room WHERE status = '1' AND id NOT IN
    (SELECT * FROM booking WHERE arrival='2/08/2013'
    OR ( arrival BETWEEN '2/08/2013' AND '22/08/2013' ))
```

Comment: your subquery is returning multiple results for a where clause. Thats why you are getting that error. Though reading your subquery, im not sure why. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: i am using WAMP MYSQL database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to your questions:

> Q1. how can i check room is available or not for customers

I suppose a room without booking is available for customers, so try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM room r
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'booking'
    FROM booking b
    WHERE b.room_id = r.id
    AND  (b.arrival BETWEEN '$arrival' AND '$departure')
)
```

> Q2. i want to show thous room list that is empty for user input date

The query is the same, if doesn't exist any booking in that interval the room is empty (so is available for booking)

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that, on the inner query, you are getting too many columns as results.

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM room WHERE status = '1' AND id NOT IN
    ( SELECT room_id FROM booking
    WHERE arrival='$arrival'
    OR ( arrival BETWEEN '$arrival' AND '$departure' ))

SELECT * FROM room WHERE status = '1' AND id NOT IN
    ( SELECT room_id FROM booking
    WHERE arrival='2/08/2013'
    OR ( arrival BETWEEN '2/08/2013' AND '22/08/2013' ))
```

Comment: how would changing the column name make any difference?

Comment: I think I don't understand de question. Simply replace the '*' of the inner query by "room_id". If you need to change the column name you would have to change the SQL too.

Comment: Sorry, i was having a daft moment

Comment: add a new category table 
#col-- id category des image price  quantity
#record   1,     Standard Double Room, description, 200, 10

i want to fetch category name with this query  


SELECT * FROM room WHERE status = '1' AND id NOT IN ( SELECT room_id FROM booking WHERE arrival='$arrival' OR ( arrival BETWEEN '$arrival' AND '$departure' ))

SELECT * FROM room WHERE status = '1' AND id NOT IN ( SELECT room_id FROM booking WHERE arrival='2/08/2013' OR ( arrival BETWEEN '2/08/2013' AND '22/08/2013' ))